# View Logger output in eclipse for a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

in one of my elicpse project I have come across this logger related snippet, I noticed that it is from slf4j library.

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(someclass.class);
```

Then in some point of the code i noticed this,

```
logger.debug("Found {} object",
            numberofobject);
```

My question is, when I run the program I do not see the logger output, how can I see that in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly configure the binding for slf4j. slf4j is just a facade, not a logging tool.

Since 1.6.0 if no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation.

Have a look at the officiel manual [here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) on how to configure slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to add a logging library to your project that implements the slf (just as Burkhard mentioned)
2. You need to configure the logger of your choice to log debug messages to the console (e.g. with a console appender in log4j)